# python GIL: Why need Lock when making changes to collections?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

Sorry one question, everyone knows Python has GIL, so only one thread is spinning at any one point in time.
https://opensource.com/article/17/4/grok-gil

This said, then why do we need lock when accessing/modifying collections? Appending or popping elements from a list for example. Or updating a dictionary? Operations like list.sort() also is atomic. I am guessing the answer be: Are you sure any of the operations that you're performing is "Atomic"? If not it can be pre-empted (Preemptive multi-tasking)

Thus, in general, because you're unsure how things are implemented under-the-hood, safer to just lock.acquire?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing code for your own consumption and you're 100% sure that you're sticking to CPython to execude the code in the forseeable future, then yes, you can indeed rely on GIL alone to keep most operations of basic collection types thread-safe.

But CPython is not the only Python implementation, and the Python language itself makes no guarantee of any collection operation being atomic, so if you're writing multi-threaded code for public consumption, then it's safer to use locks when making changes to collections, and not make any assumption about the presence of GIL or that any particular operation would be compiled into a single bytecode.

Comment: Thanks yes thats what I thought but would like to hear more on this subject.